# How to register a post type so I have archive page, but don't have single pages?

Tags: custom-post-types

I think the question is straight forward. I want to have archive page, but want the single pages gone. Is there a way with custom post type options?

Answer (score 1):

You can force single queries to 404 like they don't exist.

```
function wpse67329_force_mycpt_single_404() {
  if ( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'mycpt' ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header('404');
  }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse67329_force_mycpt_single_404' );
```

Comment: A little more tidy way is using same approach but redirect to archive page instead of trigerring 404. That way links from admin would remain usable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve issues like that is that I just don't link to the single pages. So if there is no link, to the outside visitor it seems like there are no single posts.